# EFS return empty file sometimes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

I has a EFS mount folder and a script to write a html file to there every 10 seconds. The html file size is around 1kb - 10kb. This folder is also service to web via Apache.
During high load, sometimes the request to html file return empty content or failed. I have no problem when I write that file to local storage instead of EFS. I guess the EFS network latency cause the problem.

I tried to mount EFS with recommend options form AWS but it not solve my problem.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: did you tried performance mode as max i/o and provisioned throughput mode?  max i/o has slithlt greater latency but is good for high throughtput paraled processing and file operations, burst through put mode increases with file size you start with 1 tib= 50 mib/seconds and mx up to 100 min but with provisioned mode you can have 1gib/second per 1 tib https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/limits.html#limits-fs-specific

Comment: @Jatin Mehrotra Thank you. I think it still not need to use provisioned throughput mode. We still have Percent IO Limit lower than 3%.

Comment: i see, so try using max io performance mode and what is your file system size?

Comment: @ndlink i encountered a very similar scenario, did you managed to solve it ?

Comment: @TommyW I must change my code to writing data to temp file, then rename. By this way we don't meet this problem anymore. I think the network latency cause reader read incomplete data file.